# How do I configure webpack to render inline code?

Tags: node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to include code in my index html and the

```
<% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.isProd) { %>
```

is actually rendering in the html, its not being parsed. I am using https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter which is the configs I am using. I know html-webpack-plugin is there. Any ideas what I am doing wrong.

the webpack config looks like this...

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.html'),
  filename: 'index.html',
}),
```

Comment: This syntax isnt for HTML, Are you using any templating engine?

Comment: No I thought this was part of html-webpack-plugin, ejs-html-loader

Comment: Thats webpack config for ejs templating engine, It's used with Node.js/Express generally.

Comment: thanks for the comment, is there any way to use the variables in the html when using...     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.html'),
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),

Comment: Which backend framework you're using?

Comment: I am using just webpack and vanilla JS